# Where can I find the locations of factories in the U.S. and Japan?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Where can I find the locations of all or many of the factories in the world, including in Japan and the United States?

Comment: What do you mean by factory? Any place where good are made? Places of a certain size?

Comment: @fgregg thank you for asking and answering. here I meant factory as place for making goods by consuming a certain amount of energy and other resources.

Answer (score 5):

In the United States, you might start by looking at water permits. Most large factories have to get permits for their waste and storm water runoff.

Here are discharge permits for Illinois. http://dataservices.epa.illinois.gov/dmrdata/dmrsearch.aspx

Storm water permits: Many industrial facilities have to get a permit for the pollution caused by water running off a location. Here's data for [Illinois](http://www.epa.state.il.us/water/permits/storm-water/noi.html)

Comment: thank you very much for your advice. that's a very good idea to check from regulation sides. I'll try this!

Answer (score 2):

[Datamyne](http://www.datamyne.com/) is a great source for finding sourcing of suppliers(factories) based on commodity descriptions OR via a product HS code. We source our US data via US Customs and posses trade data from 50 other countries globally. We are also a certified silver partner with ESRI and currently possess a map with over 600,000 companies geocoded along with Duns and Bradstreet verifiable information. http://www.datamyne.com/our-product/

Comment: Subtracted a point on a ISO Certified Database that contains factories or suppliers of goods from Japan into the US ? Not sure of the logic there, and it will take the user longer to use a "water/sewage" permit listing I'm confident than our tool. Been around since 1992, kthanx.